# Can we use a future verb with "as"

Tags: grammar, adverbs, as, relative-adverbs

I wonder whether in the case below I need to use present tense or future tense". Also, I wonder in any case what the general rule of it is. Please bear in mind that I insist on using "as" since I want to know whether it works similarly to "when", after which we cannot utilize any future tense. Sincerely, I appreciate your attention.

> From my perspective, there are currently some negative attitudes to modernity, which will be ended **as** more time **will elapse**.

or

> From my perspective, there are currently some negative attitudes to modernity, which will be ended **as** more time **elapse**.

Comment: "which will be ended" is an odd structure. I'd say "which will end".

Comment: as more time elapses or will elapse.

Answer (score 2):

"...which will be ended as more time elapses." is better than "...which will be ended as more time will elapse." The difference is that the latter has two future tense clauses occur supporting the independent clause.